# Jboss 6.x: How to configure HTTPS to my Jboss server? and How to add a HTTPS certificate from another server to my jboss server?

Tags: ssl, jboss, https

these are my questions: I need to know stepbystep how to enable HTTPS in my Jboss 6 server? 
And i have this situation:
 Im gonna connect my jboss server as a client to another server from other company. The other company gonna give me a HTTPS client certificate. I need to know stepbyestep how to add this certificate in my jboss server. Please help

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not "tell me how to configure my server".

Comment: I asked for this help because in my search i found how to create a self-sign certificate and add it to my JBoss for be the https server, but i really need is find how to add a other company certificate to my jboss for be the client of that other company server. I apprecite any help.